# Expected primary expression before ')' token, switch-case

Tags: compiler-errors, switch-statement, case

This is an example of a switch case statement in a book I'm reading and I've had trouble with other examples too but I've been able to solve them by myself. I have no idea what I'm missing.I put a comment on the line I'm having trouble with, I keep getting expected primary expression before ) token error.

```
int main()
{
    enum Days{
    Sunday=0,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday};

switch(Days) {  //expected primary-expression before ')' token
    case Sunday:
    cout<<"Sunday was named after the Sun.";
    break;

    case Monday:
    cout<<"Monday was named after the Moon.";
    break;

}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`switch` statement expects that you will pass **variable** to it, not a **type**. But you are passing **type**, which is `enum Days`. So you should declare variable of this type first:

```cpp
enum Days days = Sunday;
```

...or if you use C++ you can omit `enum`:

```cpp
Days days = Sunday;
```

Then provide this variable to switch, like that

```cpp
switch (days) {
    ...
}
```

You also probably should add `default:` section to your switch to handle error cases.

**EDIT**:

If you need to ask user for input, and I assume you are using C++, you can use `std::cin` for this:

```cpp
int day;

std::cout << "Enter day number (0..6): ";
std::cin >> day;

switch (day) {
```

But you can solve this task more elegant, like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))

int main()
{
    const char *days[] = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
                           "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
    int day;

    std::cout << "Enter day number (0..6): ";
    std::cin >> day;

    if (day < 0 || day >= ARRAY_SIZE(days)) {
        std::cerr << "Bad day" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << days[day] << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The program now compiles but the output is just "Sunday was named after the Sun." I guess what I should have asked was how to make an input where you enter 0-6 to indicate the day and output it onto the screen. I can do this with if-else-if statement but I tried to convert it to a switch-case statement and now I'm completely lost. By the way, this is C++

Comment: Ok, as for your "input" question -- see my **EDIT** in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch based on a variable or an expression. So if you declare a variable 'd' of type 'Days' you would be able to write: switch(d).